# Не могу включить компиляцию TypeScript в Idea 13

Tags: intellij-idea, typescript

У меня в меню настроек отсутствует пункт TypeScript, как показано на картинке ниже. Как его добавить? Или как подключить компиляцию иначе?

[image: Скрин-1]

Comment: у вас Community Edition?

Comment: Ultimate 13.1.4

У меня меню иначе выглядит, там раздела Languages & Frameworks вообще нет.

Comment: я думаю, что там нет этого. выход - поставить более новую версию.

Comment: увы, я пришел к аналогичному выводу